# how to get the actual enum values instead of its int values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

how to get the actual enum values instead of its int values

I have a enum class like below

```
public enum gender
{
 male,
 female,
 others
}
```

and this is my model create method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCanditae(Canditateinfo caninfo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Canditateinfo canditateinfo =  new Canditateinfo()
                {

                    CanditateAadhar = caninfo.CanditateAadhar,
                    CanditateActDoa = caninfo.CanditateActDoa,
                    CanditateName = caninfo.CanditateName,
                    CanditateAddress = caninfo.CanditateAddress,
                    CanditateAltNumber = caninfo.CanditateAltNumber,
                    CanditateId = caninfo.CanditateId,
                    CanditateDepartment = caninfo.CanditateDepartment,
                    CanditateDesignation = caninfo.CanditateDesignation,
                    CanditateDoj = caninfo.CanditateDoj,
                    CanditateEmail = caninfo.CanditateEmail,
                    CanditateGender = caninfo.CanditateGender,
                    CanditateIdNumber = caninfo.CanditateIdNumber,
                    CanditateLocation = caninfo.CanditateLocation,
                    CanditateMaritialStatus = caninfo.CanditateMaritialStatus,
                    CanditatePancard = caninfo.CanditatePancard,
                    CanditateTeam = caninfo.CanditateTeam,
                    CanditateBaseLocation = caninfo.CanditateBaseLocation,
                    CanditateManager = caninfo.CanditateManager,
                    CanditateMobile = caninfo.CanditateMobile,
                    EnteredBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username"),
                    EnteredDate = DateTime.Now,
                    IsActive = 1,
                    DeleteFlag =0
                    
                };
                _context.Canditateinfos.Add(canditateinfo);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            
            return View(nameof(Create));
        }
```

i am saving this in mysql db. here when i save the gender it is showing as '1' instead of 'male'
how to achieve it

i am saving this in mysql db. here when i save the gender it is showing as '1' instead of 'male'
how to achieve it

in my model it is of type enum as follows

public gender Gender {get; set;}

i cant save it  as int in db because they will use ssrs to take report.also i cant have a table for them in db because of the process.

Comment: This should work: `caninfo.CanditateGender.ToString();`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have another table called `Gender` with the ID and string value? So then only the ID is attached to the Candidate

Comment: @maccettura depends on if this is about *representation*, which should not go to any database, or about actual *data*.

Answer (score 0):

[Enum.GetName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=net-7.0) will do this for you, but obviously you'll need to change that column in the database to something that can hold a string value, if you haven't already.

Comment: the gender value will come from drop down and i cant implicate the gender as a constant in the model.

Comment: Why does that mean that this won't work? Your question was "how to get the actual enum value", which I interpreted to mean the name of each enumerated value. "actual enum value" doesn't really mean that, but you said you're not interested in the integer so that's all that's left isn't it? if you mean something else, it's not clear in the question IMO so you should update it.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain this is how my model is  public partial class Canditateinfo
    { Required] [ValidDropdown(ErrorMessage = "Select some valuesss")]
        public gender? CanditateGender { get; set; }} public enum gender  {select,Male,
        Female, Others   }

Answer (score -1):

```
//just pass it as a string in the database

enum.GetName(typeOf(male),1);
```

Comment: Um... `typeof` has no capital letter, and `male` is not a Type.

Comment: the gender value will come from drop down and i cant implicate the gender as a constant in the model.